# Using GOST with Corda

Tags: corda

I know Corda is crytographically agile. As part of this, can a Corda network use GOST block cipher cryptography (GOST 28147-89) in order to comply with Russia standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GOST is an encryption scheme. The only place encryption is used in Corda is in TLS communication:

- TLS 1.2 does not support GOST, although there is an RFC (https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-chudov-cryptopro-cptls-04.html)
- OpenSSL 1.1.0 and later no longer include the GOST engine (see [Can't enable GOST engine support in OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009269/cant-enable-gost-engine-support-in-openssl))
- Theoretically, Corda's crypto library (BouncyCastle) could support some of the GOST ciphers, as long as it supports all the algorithms defined in the TLS RFC
- Even if TLS supports GOST cipher suites, for a full GOST-enabled Corda, there might be a requirement for GOST root, doorman and network map keys (if they need GOST in the certificate hierarchy as well)
- I cannot see how mutually secure communication between the EU, US and the Rest of the World will be achieved, unless:

  - A company decides to run Corda in Russia only (their own Corda network with their own root certificate authority), or
  - TLS is modified to run dual algorithm encryption/hashing/signature/key-exchange. I am not aware of anything of this sort, except the Google post-quantum experiment that combined the ECC and New Hope algorithms. This means it is feasible to combine algorithms in TLS